# When using Image map with ImageMapster jQuery plugin the coords are changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, imagemap, imagemapster

I'm using the jQuery [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) plugin to create an hover effect on an image map.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that the hover effect is changing the coords, so the image looks moved when you hover.

I've checked and image seems good, no width, height, position or anything on the image is changed. But coords are changed as you can see.

Site: http://dev.marcell.co

I can't get any way to troubleshoot that as I tested all that I know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved using `scaleMap: false` as suggested by the developer on https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/issues/212

Thanks a lot to jamietre